# Can I use mysqlslap on an existing database?

Tags: mysql, benchmarking, stress-testing

Can I use [mysqlslap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlslap.html) to test specific databases/tables? Or just the mysqlslap database?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To test a specific database, use the `--create-schema` option. The options name is a bit misleading, as it does not create the schema if it already exists.

```
mysqlslap --create-schema=yourdatabase --no-drop --user=myuser -p
```

CAUTION: If you combine `--create-schema` with `--auto-generate-sql` and forget to add `--no-drop`, the schema is dropped after completion. See [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlslap.html#option_mysqlslap_create-schema) for more info.

Comment: That option name is moronic.

Comment: Just watch out with other options, as stated in the man: If the --auto-generate-sql option is also given, mysqlslap drops the schema at the end of the test run. To avoid this, use the --no-drop option as well.

Comment: For completeness of the --no-drop option: "This option was added in MySQL 5.5.12."

Comment: @Maragues Just tried  `--create-schema` it on a productive mysql 5.1 database. It dropped the database.

Comment: I tested with 10.1.22-MariaDB and an existing database. `mysqlslap` did not drop the database.

Comment: From official docs: If the --auto-generate-sql option is also given, mysqlslap drops the schema at the end of the test run. To avoid this, use the --no-drop option as well.

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan
It is recommended to use  --no-drop option as well along with create-schema option 
in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlslap.html

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the `--no-drop` option, as this is dangerous to leave it as is. ^^